# Flow with React Native 0.19.0 unexpected errors in Animated files

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I am using Flow with React Native 0.19.0. I am getting a bunch of errors in Animation files when running Flow, using the supplied `.flowConfig`:

```
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:143
143: type TimingAnimationConfigSingle = AnimationConfig & {
                                                          ^ property `delay`. Property not found in
143: type TimingAnimationConfigSingle = AnimationConfig & {
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type
```

I get four more similar errors in the same file when running `flow` inside project root.

When I ignore the file `AnimatedImplementation.js` I get problems in other files where I reference functions in `AnimatedImplementation.js`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you configured flow properly? check this http://screenwolf.org/2015/04/12/part-1-build-configuration-with-travis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Flow version is the same that your React Native version specifies in `<your_app>/node_modules/react-native/.flowconfig`. I get exactly the same error when trying to use a newer Flow version than 0.20.1 with React Native 0.19.

In my case, I resolved the issue by checking out branch `59d090c` of [Flow's GitHub repository](https://github.com/facebook/flow), which is identical to the 0.20.1 release, and compiling the source.

Alternatively, you could upgrade to React Native 0.20 in your project. The release is just around the corner and supports Flow 0.21.

Comment: It worked when I upgraded to React Native 0.20.0-rc1 when using Flow 0.21.0!